# CakePHP retrieve loop data in the select array

Tags: cakephp, select

now i got a table contact.
the contact have 2 row which is id and name.
now i got 3 user in my contact, 
1 A 
2 B 
3 C

question.

how do i make a select input as the code of below ( in cakephp ):

`<select name="contact" id="UserField">`
`<?php for($i=1;$i<=3; $i++) ?>` 
`<option value="1"><?php echo $contact['Contact']['name']; ?></option>`
`</select>`

Answer (score 0):

In your controllers action you can set a list of the names

```
$names = $this->Contact->find('list', array(
    'contain' => array(),
    'fields' => array(
        'Contact.id',
        'Contact.name'
    ),
    'order' => array(
        'Contact.name' => 'ASC'
    )
));
$this->set(compact('names'));
```

And then in your view

```
echo $this->Form->input('contact', array(
    'label' => 'Contact',
    'options' => $names
));
```